# Angular route parameter causing site to crash then redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working on this project and we are working in Angular 1.6. I've done routes and route parameters before. Mind you I was brought in to this project as a consultant, so I'm going with what they wrote, and it's been, let's just say, interesting.

**Problem**

URL format:

`https://{baseurl}/#/newPassword/{authstring}`

This is the URL that is getting clicked from a validation e-mail sent to a client when they request to change their password. Use your imagination to fill in content, as the bracket notation are placeholders for security purposes.

`authstring` is your standard encryption, base64/md5 I'm not exactly sure, probably md5. So there is nothing special.

When passing to the route of `newPassword`, the route crashes, and then it is immediately redirected to the home page of the site and a standard Windows Authentication box pops up. As seen in the image below.

[image: Auth box error]

I have no idea why this is showing up, as there is no call for it in the code anywhere to my knowledge, and this has been confirmed by other sources. It's not an IIS issue either, I have already confirmed that too. So there are two items out. The other interesting issue is why is it redirecting as well. The route clearly exists.

**Change Password Controller and Route Code**

In order to see if the current controller was the issue, I broke the controller down to it's most basic format and did a console log on `$routeParams` to see if anything changed. The same error occurs.

Here is the controller code I tested with:

```
angular.module('app').controller('newPasswordController', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
});
```

Here is what the route looks like in the router file:

```
.when("/newPassword/:auth", {
    templateUrl: "newPassword/new-password.html",
    controller: 'newPasswordController',
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are showing changepassword in the url and newpassword in the route.  I assume this is just a typo?

Comment: Yes thank you for the catch

Comment: Maybe you want to hide the url in the screenshot too, since you did it in the text ?

Comment: The code looks fine.  Are you sure it is able to access the template?  I generally have a pre-pended slash, but of course this depends on your folder structure.  Do you see a request to this html page in your developer console?  Also... your URL is in the screenshot, you may want to remove that for security.